# Bubble chart where the bubble dimension is given by the number of close points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am making a scatter plot where some points are very close one to each other, or even overlapping. I am thinking of making a bubble chart instead, where the bubble dimension is given by the number of points whose distance is < d. Is there an "high level" function to achieve this in matplotlib (or pandas, seaborn...)? If possible I would like also to change dynamically the resolution of bubbles, like when searching something in google maps and zooming in, the red circles become smaller and separated.

More or less I have an idea on how to make it "low level", with  numpy functions histogram amd digitize, and assigning the bubble size as the histogram values, but I am wondering if there is some "off the shelf" solution for it. I am not interested in javascript solutions, only python.

Comment: You can use `set_sizes` on the object you get back from `scatter`.  With an event handler listening to `xlim_changed` and `ylim_changed` events on the `axes.callbacks` object you can re-compute the sizes on zooming.

Comment: but if I have 3 overlapping point, with the set_sizes method will I create 3 overlapping "big" circles? I'd prefer one "big" circle when the points overlap

Comment: So you basically want to re-bin your data on zoom?  You can control everything about the collection via it's methods (ex sizes, colors, locations), but that is the easy part.  Sorting out how to rebin seems much more difficult.  I suggest looking it networkx and scipy.kdtree as a place to start with that (use networkx to find clusters, use kdtree to build graphs of edges given the distance constraint).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hints!

Comment: What about a hexbin?  I know it's not the same thing, but it's essentially conveying the same idea with color rather than size.  http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/hexbin_marginals.html  And they look much cooler!